# How to configure dockerd not to use some specific cpus?

Tags: docker, cpuset

all.

I want to reserve some cpus for realtime task.
I tried to use `cset` utility,(https://github.com/lpechacek/cpuset/blob/master/doc/tutorial.txt)
but failed since dockerd reserve all available cpu to its own cpuset.

Then, I reserved cpus 0~11 using `cset shield --cpus 0-10` command before launching dockerd. But it didn't work either. cpus were shielded and dockerd was launched but couldn't
start containers:

```
2021-07-19T17:11:13+09:00 myserver dockerd[59166]: time="2021-07-
19T17:11:13.267579743+09:00" level=error msg="fatal task error"
error="starting container failed: OCI runtime create failed:
container_linux.go:367: starting container process caused:
process_linux.go:340: applying cgroup configuration for process caused:
failed to write \"0-79\\n\": write /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset/docker/cpuset.cpus:
invalid argument: unknown" module=node/agent/taskmanager 
node.id=rzeijp8jgedezsli9x4ftjugc service.id=z6cz3jtf6nz4293ye50l23f2o 
task.id=qn9zcc45rvjdk50jyaycri7lg
```

The `cset` result says cpuset gets conflict:

```
# cset set --list
cset: 
     Name       CPUs-X    MEMs-X Tasks Subs Path
 ------------ ---------- - ------- - ----- ---- ----------
     root       0-79 y     0-1 y   696    3 /
   docker      ***** n   ***** n     0    0 /docker
   system      12-79 y       0 n   481    0 /system
     user       0-11 y       0 n     0    0 /user
```

I guess that I need to tell dockerd not to use reserved cpus for its cpuset but cannot find how.

Any comments or suggestions will be appreciated deeply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can set `dockerd` configuration to `/etc/docker/daemon.json`.
I set parent cgroup of docker to `/system` and the problem solved:

```
# cat /etc/docker/daemon.json 
{
  "cgroup-parent": "/system"
}
```